# How to loop in Bash until reaching free disk space limit?

Tags: bash, while-loop, disk

I would like to do a set of operations (`x y z`) as long as I have at least 200MB free space on file-system mounted to `/media/z`.

How can I do that?

I tried something like

```
while (`df | grep /media/z | awk '{print $4}'` > 204800); do x; y; z; done;
```

but I guess my `while` syntax is wrong.

Comment: grep + awk is a useless use of grep, because awk can do all the job; in fact, you can write "awk '/\/media\/z/{print $4}' and get exactly the same result.

Comment: This will probably execute faster: `df /media/z | awk 'NR==2{print $4}'`

Answer (score 6):

`( )` executes a command in a sub-shell. If you want to test a condition you have to use *test* command: `[ ]`.

```
while [ `df | grep /media/z | awk '{print $4}'` -gt 204800 ]; do 
    x; y; z; sleep 5; 
done;
```

Comment: that would be `-gt` rather that `>` (which is output redirection)

Comment: Also, in Bash, one can perform maths using <code>$(( 4 + 5))</code>.

Comment: @fredden: In comments, use backticks instead of <code> for code samples.

Comment: Instead of `df | grep /media/z` you can use `df -h /media/z` which will unambiguously select a disk if two or more disks have "z" as the starting volume name, as `df -h` will only select disks that have that exact match

Answer (score 2):

if you're using bash use [[ ]] to use the internal testing, it's faster and gives you standard operators:

```
while (( $(df /media/z | awk 'NR==2{print $4}') > 204800 )); do
    x; y; z
done
```

Comment: +1 Plus, as you've shown, `$()` is preferable over backticks.

Comment: Use `-gt` for numeric comparison.  `>` does string comparison (e.g. `[[ 5 > 204800 ]]` evaluates to true, but `[[ 5 -gt 204800 ]]` does not).

Comment: @Gordon You're right I should've used (( > )), fixed now, thanks.